# Software to Calculate Kernighan-Lin Algorithm on Graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, math-software

Is there any (free) software out there that can perform the Kernighan-Lin partitioning algorithm on a small graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm aware of Chaco which is an open-source graph partitioning package written in C language. Chaco can do KL as well as many other partitioning heuristics. You can download it from

http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~algorith/implement/chaco/implement.shtml

And user's guide is here

https://cfwebprod.sandia.gov/cfdocs/CompResearch/docs/guide.pdf